# vbscript output in Hebrew

Tags: vbscript, hebrew, inputbox

I have this VBS file:

```
Dim retval 
retval = InputBox("חיפוש - הכנס את מילת החיפוש","Setting Membership Club") 

If IsEmpty(retval) Then 
    'cancelled 
    WScript.Echo ("EXITSP1") 
Else 
    'something has entered even zero-length 
    WScript.Echo retVal 
End If
```

and here is how I call it:

```
cscript //nologo D:\inputbox.vbs > D:\outputbox.txt
```

But the outputbox.txt file will take me to Gibrish

I want it to come out in Hebrew

[image: input box screenshot showing Hebrew]

[image: result file screnshot showing garbage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use shell redirection to write the output file. You can make it work, but it depends on too many factors that your program can't control to work reliably, and therefore it will cause all kinds of headaches.

Use the FileSystemObject and tell it to write a Unicode file.

```
Dim FSO, retval, outFile
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'                 CreateTextFile(filename, [overwrite, [unicode]])
Set outFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("outputbox.txt", True, True)

retval = InputBox("חיפוש - הכנס את מילת החיפוש", "Setting Membership Club") 
If IsEmpty(retval) Then
    outFile.Write "EXITSP1"
Else
    outFile.Write retval
End If

outfile.Close
```

Documentation for the FileSystemObject (and the CreateFile method): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method